# Transform row in column in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to rotate the visualization of a table showing the lines as columns without any kind of aggregation.

Suppose I have this table

```
create table user  
    id       int,  
    name     nvarchar(100),  
    company  nvarchar(100),  
    division nvarchar(100),  
    city     nvarchar(100)
```

that can be retrieved with this select

```
select name,company division, city from user order by id
```

wich gives me this result

```
john    Company1   division1   City1  
Peter   Company2   division2   City2  
Mary    Company3   division3   City3 
.
.
```

but what I need is to show each line as a column and the first column with the name of the field like this

```
Name     john        Peter      Mary       ....  
Company  Company1    Company2   Company3   ....  
Division division1   division2  division3  ....  
City     City1       City2      City3      ....
```

How can I accomplish this? I Tried using this unpivot

```
select col,value
from
    (select cast(name as varchar) as name,
            cast(Company as varchar) as company,
            cast(Division as varchar) as division
            cast(City as varchar) as city
        from user) p
    unpivot
    (value for col in (name,company,division,city)) as unpvt
```

but this is what I got (Note: I want all the names in the same row)

```
name     john  
Company  Company1  
Division division1  
City     City1  
name     peter             // this should be in the first row as a second column  
Company  Company2          
Division division2  
City     City2
...
```

Comment: How if you have many users name? You will have very long columns list.  Difficult to manage.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo I am aware of this problem. The worst case at moment will give 682 columns but it is a request of the client. I will implement filters in the query trying to limit the problem but it is all I can do abou that.

Comment: I suggest you better manage it in your application level. Not in db level.

Comment: The filters will be parameters the client will have access in the screen where he will choose to generate the file creation (the output will be exported to Excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is super ugly, but it's the only way I could figure out how to do what you want solely in SQL Server. If you copy and paste the code it should run and give you results and leave your database clean. I use a couple permanent tables to work around some dynamic sql scoping limitations, but I drop them both before it's done.

```
If      Object_ID('tempdb..#userInfo') Is Not Null Drop Table #userInfo
Create  Table #userInfo (id Int, name Varchar(100), company Varchar(100), division Varchar(100), city Varchar(100))

Insert  #userInfo (id, name, company, division, city)
Values  (1, 'john','company1', 'division1', 'city1'),
        (2, 'peter','company2', 'division2', 'city2'),
        (3, 'mary','company3', 'division3', 'city3'),
        (4, 'timmy','company4', 'division4', 'city4'),
        (5, 'nancy','company5', 'division5', 'city5'),
        (6, 'james','company6', 'division6', 'city6'),
        (7, 'brandon','company7', 'division7', 'city7'),
        (8, 'jay','company8', 'division8', 'city8')

If      Object_ID('tempdb..#unPivoted') Is Not Null Drop Table #unPivoted
Create  Table #unPivoted (id Int, rid Int, col Varchar(100), value Varchar(100))

Insert  #unPivoted
Select  id, Row_Number() Over (Partition By id Order By value) As rID, col, value
From    #userInfo p
Unpivot (value For col In (name, company, division, city)) As u

If      Object_ID('dbo.TempQueryOutput') Is Not Null Drop Table dbo.TempQueryOutput

Select  1 As OrderCol,'City' As ColName Into dbo.TempQueryOutput
Union
Select  2,'Company'
Union
Select  3,'Division'
Union
Select  4,'Name'


Declare @sql Nvarchar(Max),
        @maxID Int,
        @loopIter Int = 1

Select  @maxID = Max(id)
From    #userInfo

While   @loopIter <= @maxID
Begin
        Set     @sql = 'Select  o.*, u.value As Col' + Convert(Nvarchar(100),@loopIter) + ' Into dbo.TempQueryTable
                        From    dbo.TempQueryOutput o
                        Join    #unPivoted u
                                On  o.OrderCol = u.rid
                                And u.id = ' + Convert(Nvarchar(100),@loopIter)

        Exec    sp_executeSQL @sql

        If      Object_ID('dbo.TempQueryOutput') Is Not Null Drop Table dbo.TempQueryOutput

        Select  * Into dbo.TempQueryOutput
        From    dbo.TempQueryTable

        If      Object_ID('dbo.TempQueryTable') Is Not Null Drop Table dbo.TempQueryTable

        Set     @loopIter = @loopIter + 1

End

Update  dbo.TempQueryOutput
Set     OrderCol =  Case 
                    When ColName = 'Name' Then 1
                    When ColName = 'Company' Then 2
                    When ColName = 'Division' Then 3
                    When ColName = 'City' Then 4
                    End

Select  *
From    dbo.TempQueryOutput
Order   By OrderCol             

If      Object_ID('dbo.TempQueryOutput') Is Not Null Drop Table dbo.TempQueryOutput
```

Comment: Thank you. I think there is nothing better than that .